# Changing Content of JTable Cells Individually

Tags: java, jtable, jpanel, cell, imageicon

So Suppose I create a JTable with a specific number of columns and rows. Is it possible to add a JPanel to a specific cell after the JTable is already initialized? The JTable would be empty at first and then I would change a cell at row X and column Y to instead contain a JPanel which would contain an amount of ImageIcons. I don't have any code to put here really, I just need to know what I would have to use to accomplish this and how. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the data in the table you use:

```
table.setValueAt(...);
```

This will update the data in the TableModel.

However, adding a JPanel to the table is not the way a table is designed to be used. Typically you add data to the model. Then you use a `renderer` to display the data in a cell.

Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for more information and examples.